# Determine scanner architecture, flatbad or feeder, WIA

Tags: vba, scanning

I am trying to write a function (in VBA) that will scan a single page if the scanner has a flatbad architecture, or multiple if it has a feeder. I am using Windows Image Acquisition 2.0 on Windows XP. The following line of code reutrns an error:

```
MsgBox wiaScanner.Properties("3086").Value
```

In [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can see that property 3086 stands for Document Handling Capabilities. When I run it I get "ID not found". This worked fine on windows 7. I'm sure there's an alternative way for windows XP, I just couldn't find it.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `wiaScanner.Properties(3086).Value` - ie. without the quotes ?

Comment: If I do that, I get "index out of range". MSDN documentation isn't clear on this matter